# Is it possible to use route 53 to redirect http to https for the same link?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, redirect, amazon-route53

I need to redirect my link from HTTP to HTTPS using route 53. I am running my app on heroku and using the domain from route 53.

Is there a way to redirect all HTTP links to HTTPS without meddling with the server-side code?

For example, using example.com, when going to http://example.com, I would want it to redirect to https://example.com. There is no need to redirect it to https://www.example.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route 53 is a DNS service only for mapping domains to resolvable records, redirects are not part of the service provided here.

If you're interested in performing a HTTP to HTTPS redirect without having to apply any configurations or code changes within your application there a couple of services that can perform the redirect for you. However, as you're using Heroku an Application Load Balancer would not be applicable.

[CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) is AWS managed CDN service, by adding this in front of your application you can [enable HTTP to HTTPS redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html) in the distribution configuration. You would then use an Alias record in Route 53 to resolve your domain to the CloudFront CNAME you're provided.

**In addition** for general context the below option can also be used when the host is in AWS, or the ALB can communicate to it via a private IP address.

For AWS based hosts (or IP based hosts) AWS can also perform redirects via a [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) which supports any complex redirect rules, including the ability to [redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/). Application hosts would be added to the ALB via a target group and would become private to avoid any direct communication.

Comment: I read about the cloud front solution. The issue is the domain in route53 is a cname record to herokudns. So how do I set up cloud front and achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Route53 isn't involved in serving the request, it's just involved in the DNS resolution, so no it's not possible.